# how to store session data into custom storage in bot builder

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using node js to build chat bot.

I'm currently storing session data into Microsoft default storage, which have a limit of 64K per user session. I want to use my own storage to store session data. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1943) is what I got help from Microsoft developer.

I am able to store in document DB and Azure table.

Still, I am confused. How we will implement the `IStorageClient` interface to store in own DB?

Whenever I set `session.UserData.name=""` it should store in own DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I written code to store bot data into Mongo Db.
Full code and details can find in [BotBuilder-MongoDB](https://github.com/proarchgithub/msbotframework-mongo-middlelayer)

IstorageClient 
Interface implementation code:

```
"use strict";
var Consts = require('./Consts');
var mongodb_1 = require("mongodb");
var replaceDot_Atrate = require("./replaceDot");
var mongoDbConnection = require('./connection.js');
var conf = require('../config');
var conversational_collname = conf.db.conversationalCollection;

var IStorageClient = (function () {

    function IStorageClient(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    IStorageClient.prototype.retrieve = function (partitionKey, rowKey, callback) {
        var id = partitionKey + ',' + rowKey;
        if(rowKey!=="userData"){
            var query={"$and":[{"userid":id}]}
                mongoDbConnection(function(err,db) {
                var iterator= db.collection(conversational_collname).find(query);
                iterator.toArray(function (error, result, responseHeaders) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("Error",error)
                        callback(error, null, null);
                    }
                    else if (result.length == 0) {
                        callback(null, null, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        var document_1 = result[0];
                        var finaldoc=replaceDot_Atrate.substituteKeyDeep(document_1, /\@/g, '.');
                        finaldoc["id"]=id
                        callback(null, finaldoc, null);
                    }
                });
            }); 
        }
        else{
            var query={"$and":[{"userid":partitionKey}]}
            mongoDbConnection(function(err,db) { 

                var iterator= db.collection(conversational_collname).find(query);
                iterator.toArray(function (error, result, responseHeaders) {
                    if (error) {
                        callback(error, null, null);
                    }
                    else if (result.length == 0) {
                        //console.log("result length 0")
                        callback(null, null, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        var document_1 = result[0];
                        callback(null, document_1, null);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };

    IStorageClient.prototype.initialize = function (callback) {
        var _this = this;
        var client=mongodb_1.MongoClient;
        this.client = client;

        mongoDbConnection(function(err,database) {    
                _this.database = database;
                _this.collection = database.collection(conversational_collname);
                callback(null);
         });
    };

    IStorageClient.prototype.insertOrReplace = function (partitionKey, rowKey, entity, isCompressed, callback) {
        var id=partitionKey + ',' + rowKey
        var docDbEntity = { id: partitionKey + ',' + rowKey, data: entity, isCompressed: isCompressed };
        if(rowKey!=="userData"){
            var newEntitiy=replaceDot_Atrate.substituteKeyDeep(entity, /\./g, '@');
            var conditions1 = {
                'userid': id
            };
            var updateobj1 = {
                "$set": {"data":newEntitiy,"isCompressed":false}
            };   
            mongoDbConnection(function(error,db) {    
                db.collection(conversational_collname).update(conditions1,updateobj1,{upsert: true},function(err,res){
                callback(error, null,"");
            });
            });
        }
        else{
            var conditions = {
                'userid': partitionKey
            };
            var update = {
                "$set": {"data":entity}
            }
            mongoDbConnection(function(error,db) {    
                db.collection(conversational_collname).update(conditions,update,{upsert: true},function(err,res){
                callback(error, null,"");
           })
        });
        } 
    };


    IStorageClient.getError = function (error) {
        if (!error)
            return null;
        return new Error('Error Code: ' + error.code + ' Error Body: ' + error.body);
    };

    return IStorageClient;
}());
exports.IStorageClient = IStorageClient;
```

Comment: While the linked repository may be an example of what you describe, you should summarize the relevant parts here.

Comment: very very bad idea, have you seen how many entries it creates? i was chatting with the bot it stored 100 records within 2 mins for a conversation. Imagine what happens when 1000s of your users are chatting simultaneously, what you wanna do is only store the user id and name the first time they chat

Comment: @PirateApp , I implemented interface which Microsoft provide, even you use Redis or Microsoft Document db, number of call will be same.  And for your information, we are using this layer since last 1 year with 500 user approx, ans it is fast enough.

Comment: @AakashKag have you tried it with a bigger audience set by any chance? curious to see if any metrics are available

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I got the issue; I understand what you are trying to do and it seems you have all the pieces in place.

First, you have to implement the [IStorageClient](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/IStorageClient.ts) interface. In your implementation, you write the logic to store things in your DB.

You can review the [DocumentDB](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/DocumentDbClient.ts) and [Azure Tables](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/AzureTableClient.ts) implementations to get an idea of how that can be implemented.

Now, the question is.. if your custom storage is in Azure..., then you might be able to use the [AzureBotStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/Node/src/AzureBotStorage.ts) with your custom storage client. You instantiate your custom storage client, pass a reference to the `AzureBotStorage` and set that as the storage in the bot

```
// Azure DocumentDb State Store
var docDbClient = new azure.DocumentDbClient({
    host: process.env.DOCUMENT_DB_HOST,
    masterKey: process.env.DOCUMENT_DB_MASTER_KEY,
    database: process.env.DOCUMENT_DB_DATABASE,
    collection: process.env.DOCUMENT_DB_COLLECTION
});
var botStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);

// Set Custom Store
bot.set('storage', botStorage);
```

If your custom storage is in any other place than Azure, then `AzureBotStorage` might not work for you. Please note that I'm not sure of this, you will have to check the code to confirm. From what I saw, it seems pretty generic, and so you might be able to reuse it and just implement `IStorageClient`. If that's not the case, you will have to also implement the [IBotStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/calling/src/storage/BotStorage.ts#L50) interface.

At the end, `AzureBotStorage` is doing that. It implements `IBotStorage` and uses an `IStorageClient` to interact with the actual provider.

Comment: Thanks For quick reply. I already tried to store into Document Db and azure table. both example are working fine for me. But i want to use mongo db which is located into my own server. I am new to node js. Got confused how I can implement IStorageClient interface.  You can see what Microsoft devs are suggesting https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1943

Comment: I know what they are suggesting. But I don't understand your issue. You are looking for someone to write the code for you? You implement that interface and put the code to interact with Mongo DB. There isn't much more than that

Comment: yeah exactly . if some one provide how we will code it. I am very much familiar with Mongo. I can code node js with Mongo. But not able to get how i can use this interface.. I was looking for sample example of IStorageClient  . Or at least  some basic logic .Rest logic for Mongo code i will do .

Comment: But the examples are basically those I put you in the answer. I linked to the code to both the document DB and Azure table implementation. Is just an interface, you need to go implement 2 methods

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this answer on a very, very old thread just because it seems to be on the top results for implementing custom storage options for Bot Framework.

There's a considerably easier solution that does not involve using npms that have not been updated in a while that carry a risk of not being auditable for corporate environments or that will flood your console with huge amounts of log entries.

The easiest way is to create your own Data Storage code for your bot using the most up-to-date driver for the db of your choice by following the steps in this [Undocumented Guide for Custom Data Storage in Microsoft Bot Framework](https://medium.com/@kamidipreetham/the-undocumented-guide-for-custom-data-storage-in-microsoft-bot-framework-49a57cfaaaa2)

It took me about an hour to implement for MongoDB, including some learning curve for their newest driver.

In short, in case the link dies at some point, you can create a middleware that exports two key functions that Bot Framework is looking for: `getData` and `saveData`. Each of these have to have the following rough structure (from the link using Redis):

```
var storageKey = 'conversationId';
module.exports = {
getData : (data, callback) => {
    redisClient.get(data[storageKey], (err, reply) => {
        if (err || !reply) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, JSON.parse(reply));
        }
    })
},
saveData : (data, value, callback) => {
        redisClient.set(data[storageKey], JSON.stringify(value), (err, reply) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else if (reply === 'OK') {
                callback(null);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then, in your `app.js`, be sure to `require()` your middleware and set it accordingly:

```
const dbMiddleware = require('./path/to/middleware')

bot.set('storage', dbMiddleware)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on this library: [mongo-bot-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-bot-storage)

```
import {MongoDbBotStorage, MongoDBStorageClient} from "mongo-bot-storage";

// use it like this 
bot.set("storage", new MongoDbBotStorage(new MongoDBStorageClient({
    url: "mongodb://localhost/mydb",
    mongoOptions: {}
})));

// or like this
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb", (error, db) => {
    bot.set("storage", new MongoDbBotStorage(new MongoDBStorageClient({db})));
});
```

and then use the default `session.userData`, etc..

don't forget to

```
// Enable Conversation Data persistence
bot.set('persistConversationData', true);
```

Comment: fixed it. though that clicking on a link and reading the information over there will be sufficient, as this one is an _actual_ library and not some kind of _hack together half a project_ thing in accepted answer

Comment: @PaulRysevets you copied my solution, What's new in your solution except npm?? In what way it is better then my solution ?   https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3095

Comment: @AakashKag, did you, actually, read the answers on that thread that you linked? Do you understand what is "not that good" with your code?

Comment: I create npm module also, It is faster then my older solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-mongodb                                                 https://github.com/Manacola/msbotframework-mongo-middlelayer